# Amazon S3 Java SDK multiple files upload

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

What I need is to download many files from Internet and upload them to S3 as fast as it possible. For now I open every file as a stream and upload them one after another. The average speed of this approach is one picture per second. What's the fastest way to achieve this?

Comment: Lots of ideas. However, without seeing your current code and performance statistics, I don't know if any of them will be worthwhile. Perhaps you should edit your question to provide more information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Split in parts and upload in parallel would be a good start, the [TransferManager class](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html) can help with that.
Also, the article ["Pushing the Limits of S3 Upload Performance"](http://improve.dk/pushing-the-limits-of-amazon-s3-upload-performance/) has some nice ideas on the subject.

Comment: It *might* work. Unless, of course, the OP has already used up all of the bandwidth he/she has available.